# Fast algorithm to allocate and release integer-like handles in C++

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, vector, handle

I need a class that can allocate a unique integer (handle) and assign it to something object.
And then release it in order to be used later.
This algorithm should be fast. What data structure should I use? `vector` is fast to access data but long to erase or add(but it also important), `list` is long to access data.
Maybe you know some good implementations?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what your use-case is, but `malloc(1)` or `new char;` will return a unique address until that allocated unit is freed or deleted.

Comment: why would a linkedlist be slow for access if you only have a single node?

Comment: Are you expecting to manage 1,000 of these handles?  Or 1,000,000?  Or more?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Why do you need to use handles instead of pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use 64-bit integers. For allocation, I'd use a simple counter. To deallocate...well, I'd simply ignore the request to free a handle.

You can ignore deallocation, because with 64-bit handles, you can quite literally allocate handles for decades at a time without even coming close to running out of fresh handles to allocate.